# C - Semaphore Rights Issue

Tags: c, semaphore

I tried to allow other user's program to modify my semaphore ( Basically remove it) , but It is failing.

Below is my semaphore creation command:

```
  if ((semID = semget(key, 2, IPC_CREAT | 0777)) == -1) {
    perror("Sem Creation:");
              exit(2);
   }
```

Still programs which are run by other's users are unable to delete semaphore with error that " Not owner"

Comment: Your permissions are probably getting changed by the user's `umask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the man page for `semctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semctl.2.html):

> IPC_RMID Immediately remove the semaphore set, awakening all processes blocked in semop(2) calls on the set (with an error return and errno set to EIDRM). The effective user ID of the calling process must match the creator or owner of the semaphore set, or the caller must be privileged.

So the process trying to remove the semaphore must have the user ID of the owner or creator or be superuser.

Edit: You can use `semctl()` with the `IPC_SET` option to set the `uid` field (owner id) of the semaphore's `ipc_perm` structure.  That way you can transfer ownership to another user id (the creator id is not changed).  See the man page I linked to and read the section for `IPC_SET`.

Comment: can't I give rights(somehow) to other process/user to remove the semaphore ?

Answer (score 0):

```
here is what you need to know about semaphore creation/removal
Notice that a named semaphore is created using sem_open() NOT semget()


   POSIX semaphores come in two forms: named semaphores and unnamed
   semaphores.

   Named semaphores
          A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form
          /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to
          NAME_MAX-4 (i.e., 251) characters consisting of an initial
          slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are
          slashes.  Two processes can operate on the same named
          semaphore by passing the same name to sem_open(3).

          The sem_open(3) function creates a new named semaphore or
          opens an existing named semaphore.  After the semaphore has
          been opened, it can be operated on using sem_post(3) and
          sem_wait(3).  When a process has finished using the semaphore,
          it can use sem_close(3) to close the semaphore.  When all
          processes have finished using the semaphore, it can be removed
          from the system using sem_unlink(3).
```